# iptables routing local network traffic

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have router works like this

```
internet -> 1.2.3.4 eth1 -> Router <- eth0 10.0.0.1 - LAN
```

and want to port forward port 80 from 1.2.3.4 to 10.0.0.10

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:80
```

this works perfectly from interntet, but not from LAN network ex.IP 10.0.0.2
how  can i achieve that? (i dont want to use DNS for that)

P.S.: i need to access 1.2.3.4:80 from both networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure all traffic runs back through your router (so it can rewrite it).

A POSTROUTING rule can achieve this. (see: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-10.html)

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.0.10 -s 10.0.0.0/24 \
    -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.1`
```

Comment: thx it works perfectly

Comment: Heel erg bedankt, je bent de beste!